# TYPO3 powermail - change transalation of one field in form

Tags: typo3, typoscript, powermail

I'm looking for TypoScript configuration for powermail to change a validation mandatory message of one field - type: **file upload**. Unfortunately this one type don't have a option to specify custom validation...

Maybe there is an option to get the form and field by TypoScript like:

```
[globalString = GP:tx_powermail_pi1|field|form_title = formTitle] && [filed ID or marker]
    plugin.tx_powermail {
        _LOCAL_LANG.default {
            validationerror_mandatory = validation message
        }
    }
[global]
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using more then one upload fields within one form it's not possible to change the validation message just for one at the moment. But if you are just dealing with one file field, you could set an extension template to the page where the form is located.

Comment: I'm using a set of different mandatory fields in few forms on one page, so it's not a solution. 
I find already hardcode solution - changing the data-parsley message with JS, but i like to have clean code.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this. For more Info [click](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/powermail/1.6.11/Powermail/Features/ValidationOfFieldValues/Index.html)

```
plugin.tx_powermail_pi1 {
  validate.uid41.auto = email
  validate.uid41.errormsg = Please check your email, there is an error!
}
```

Comment: This is configuration for powermail 1.6.X version from 2012. This typoscript will no't work with current 3.X